# How to hide treecols in treeview?

Tags: treeview, firefox-addon, xul

I try to hide `treecols` in `treeview` in XUL by setting style to `display: none`. The labels of treeview rows also disappear however. How can I hide treecols while keeping rows visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* that you mean to hide the column headers in a `tree` element. The `tree` element supports hiding individual columns so when you use `display: none` style on a column header the entire column is hidden with it. Instead you should use `height: 0px; overflow: hidden;` style on the `treecols` element - technically speaking it won't be hidden then but it won't be visible on screen either.

Comment: I was also trying `height: 0px` (also with `!important`), but it does nothing. Is it working for you? (I am testing it on `threadTree` in Thunderbird 12.0.1 )

Comment: No, on this tree it doesn't work - I've updated my answer, apparently the header overflows there.